# How to calculate a capacitance of a probe in a equivalent circuit of oscilloscope?

Tags: capacitor, circuit-analysis, oscilloscope, capacitance, transfer-function

[image]

I want to caculate **the value of capacitance of probe** which makes the transfer function H(s) from V_in to V_out become equal to 1/10 at all frequencies.

How can I calculate it?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Google capacitive voltage divider and set V_in to V_out to become equal to 1/10 for  capacitive voltage divider also.

Comment: You mean that there is a computing program on the search result? Something like Wolfram alpha

Comment: No, just an equation V_out/ V_in = C1/(C1 + C2) where C2 = 50pF+ 16pF.

Comment: Oh, I understand the total capacitance for capacitors in parallel and voltage division over capacitors in series, and it seems resistors placed in parallel or between capacitors don't have any effect on capacitive voltage division. Why is it?

Comment: Why? becouse thsi is only true if  C1/(C1 + C2) = R2/(R1 + R2) or R1*C1 = C2*R2

Comment: Where is V_in? Does it have any source impedance that should be accounted for?

Comment: @G36 Oh, ok I'll take that and study about it. Thanks!

Comment: @Andyaka  V_in is on the left side of the probe and V_out is on the right side of Oscilloscope input. That picture explains how oscilloscope get a 1/10 of the voltage value measured by oscilloscope probe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\$\frac{1}{10} \$ ratio is set by the voltage divider:

\$ H(s=0)=\frac{R_{osc}}{R_{osc}+R_{probe}}\$

In order to get a flat attenuation the following condition has to be verified:
\$ R_{probe}C_{probe}=R_{osc}(C_{osc}+C_{cable}) \$ that means:
\$ C_{probe}=\frac{R_{osc}(C_{osc}+C_{cable})}{R_{probe}}\$